# Merge shapefiles using ogr2ogr and retrieve the attributes of both

Tags: shapefile, ogr2ogr, merge, union

I have two shapefiles that I want merge (overlay/intersect) having in the destination the attributes of the two sources file.

```
ogr2ogr file_merged.shp tl_2010_us_uac10_conus_albersUA.shp
ogr2ogr -update -append file_merged.shp tabblock2010_10_pophu.shp -nln file_merged
```

In this way I obtain the polygons of the two shapes, but I lose the attributes of the `tabblock2010_10_pophu.shp`.

My final aim is then make an SQL statement where I can retrieve polygon in common in the both shapes.

Any suggestions??

Comment: sql query? You're using some kind of a database? You can easly do that kind of spatial queries using postgis

Comment: Thanks menjaraz,
i will test it.
Actually i think should be possible with ogr2ogr by using sql statement.
I tried several combination but not i did not succeed.
Let's see if somebody else reply.
Ciao Giuseppe

Answer (score 11):

Using **GDAL >= 1.10.0** and its **[OGR Virtual Format](http://www.gdal.org/drv_vrt.html)**, we can write a `VRT` file named, for example, `merge.vrt` (see *Example: Union layer (GDAL >= 1.10.0)*):

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTUnionLayer name="unionLayer">
        <OGRVRTLayer name="source1">
            <SrcDataSource>source1.shp</SrcDataSource>
        </OGRVRTLayer>
        <OGRVRTLayer name="source2">
            <SrcDataSource>source2.shp</SrcDataSource>
        </OGRVRTLayer>
    </OGRVRTUnionLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

and simply execute in order to simply preserve the attributes of both SHPs:

```
ogr2ogr merge.shp merge.vrt
```

Instead, if you want also exclude duplicate geometries from the result:

```
ogr2ogr merge_distinct.shp merge.vrt -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT DISTINCT geometry, * FROM merge"
```

Comment: +1 because this is ultra cool, but will it allow the OP to do the intersection/conflation stuff they mention? ::bows::

Comment: @elrobis I have updated the answer, because you make me notice that the second question was unanswered. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, great answer, just an update for the final ogr2ogr statement. instead of "* FROM merge" for your example you want "* FROM unionLayer", since it was defined as unionLayer in your vrt. Also for those unfamiliar with vrt's in ogr your name="source1" will have to be the same as the name of your shapefile, so: <OGRVRTLayer name="myshapefile">
            <SrcDataSource>myshapefile.shp</SrcDataSource>

Answer (score 5):

I wrote some downloadable code for that. A simple python program to combine shapefiles in many ways: http://gistncase.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/python-shapefile-merger-utility.html

By default performs the *dbf schemes union* and it adds an *attribute filled with the source shapefile name*, so you can recognize records.

This is the commandline for your needs:

```
python shapemerger.py -o file_merged.shp tl_2010_us_uac10_conus_albersUA.shp tabblock2010_10_pophu.shp
```

(you have to run it in a python environment with available ogr/gdal packages. I wrote some note about this above the code)

Comment: Looks like the post has moved here: http://gistncase.blogspot.com/2012/05/python-shapefile-merger-utility.html