# Performing multilayer intersection in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector, intersection

This question on Multilayer intersection in QGIS was asked by "julsbreakdown" a year go. But I am a newbie and I am not really sure how it works with SQL as suggested in the responses. And I am using the same image posted by "julsbreakdown." Here is the link of the previous thread: [Multiple layer intersection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155521/multiple-layer-intersection)

**Using QGIS (or its plug-in) or python script, how do I get the polygon (x) which is the intersection of four polygons?**

[image]

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using? As one of the comments in the question you posted says "since qgis 2.14.3 the processing algorithm now take a list of layers". If you go to Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Intersection you will see if you can enter more than two layers as inputs

Comment: Your options for drawing attention to an old unanswered question when you have a reputation of less than 50 are outlined at https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4011/115

Comment: Thanks firefly-orange! I checked it but the geoprocessing tool only offers intersection of two vector layers. As for the algorithm or python script, I just have no idea how it works. But I am starting to look at the introduction to python script, but it will take some time. But if you know other ways or you know the python script for the multilayer intersection, please share it to me. Thanks!

Comment: @firefly-orange - I think perhaps you meant the `Merge` tool? =)

Comment: @user18131 - I [posted a comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155521/performing-multiple-layer-intersection-in-qgis#comment382223_155521) on the original question which might help a little :)